# ¿Como obtener la primera letra y vocal de un string en xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Quiero obtener la primera letra y vocal del apellido paterno para obtener el rfc

```
string rfc = "";
            rfc += apellidoPaterno.Substring(0, 2);
            rfc += nombre.Substring(0, 1);
            rfc += apellidoMaterno.Substring(0, 1);
```

Comment: Qué es un `rfc`???

Comment: El Registro Federal de Contribuyentes

Comment: por ejemplo si tu apellido es "Lopez" que retorne la `o` ??

Comment: Sip pero ya pude, ya conteste mi pregunta por si gustas ver la respuesta

Comment: Lo que pasa es que tienes que arreglar tu pregunta para que cualquiera pueda contestarla, de lo contario te la van a cerrar. Y la verdad es que no se entiende bien lo que quieres porque eso del `rfc` es de un país en particular. Luego tu respuesta es incorrecta, así que debes corregirla

Answer (score 0):

Lo logre hacer con un foreach donde primero declaro una matriz "vocales" donde guardo las vocales, después declaro la variable "vocal" que es un string vacio donde se guardara la vocal, luego hice un for each que recorre la variable "apellidoPaterno" con "i". Si "i" contiene una letra de la matriz "vocales" me guardara ese valor en la variable "vocal" y la convierto a string

```
 //Obtener la primera vocal del apellido
            char[] vocales = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
            string vocal = "";
            foreach (char i in apellidoPaterno)
            {
                if(vocales.Contains(i))
                {
                    vocal = i.ToString();
                }
            }
```